# Not using a duplicate number when using a decrement

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program using a loop with a decrement and not to be able to use the same number twice. If using the same number, I would want a "invalid number" displayed. It is a number system set up to read numbers between 10 and 100.  If it goes over 100, "invalid number" is displayed. This is what I have so far:
            string userNumber;
            int userNumberInt;
            int previousNumber = 0;

```
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter++)
                   {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your number");
            userNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            userNumberInt = Convert.ToInt32(userNumber);

            if ((userNumberInt <= 100) && (userNumberInt >= 10))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is " + userNumber);
                previousNumber = userNumberInt;

            }
                else if 
                (previousNumber == userNumberInt)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Number is invalid."); 
            }

            // number is invalid

            else

            // number is valid
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number.");
                counter--;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();  // for last enter key
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks something `HashSet<int>` would easily solve.

Comment: _"...set up to red"_ -- do you mean "set up to read"? If so, read from where? How do you want to display "invalid number"? What is the context here? Your question is as stated so far far too vague to understand, never mind answer.

Comment: sorry, I did put more information in

Answer (score 0):

With your use of previous, the same numbers could be entered.  For example, the first number entered could be 12, so 12 becomes previousNumber.  Then when you enter 12 again you'll display "invalid number" which is good, but you enter 13, then 13 becomes the previousNumber and now you can enter 12 again.  So what you should do is store all of your valid numbers in a list and check if your userInput is in the list so that you're not using duplicate numbers.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> validInputs = new List<int>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        string stringInput = Console.ReadLine();

        int numberInput;
        if (int.TryParse(stringInput, out numberInput))
        {
            if ((10 <= numberInput && numberInput <= 100) &&
                validInputs.Contains(numberInput) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number is valid");
                validInputs.Add(numberInput);
            }
            else
            {
                // This is not a valid number cause it's not in the range or it's a duplicate
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
                counter--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // This is not a valid number
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
```